# RelationShip Between Camera and View Matrix

Tags: opengl, graphics

Why the View Matrix is inverse of A Camera Matrix ? I can't understand this relationship can anyone please explain this to me.
Formally Vector to a camera is calculated as follow

```
toCameraVector= (inverse(viewMatrix)*vec4(0,0,0,1.0)).xyz-worldPosition.xyz;
```

Comment: see [understand 4x4 homogenous matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) if you multiply by direct matrix you are going from local space to global space and if by inverse then you are going back .... so object matrix represents object position and orientation in space and is used to convert to world global coordinates and the camera transforms from that to camera/screen local coordinates after scaling/projection the coordinates are in pixels of the screen ...

Answer (score 2):

A camera in the 3D world is actually an imaginary object. There is no actual camera. So we need to simulate camera by doing things the opposite way. If we need to move the camera to the left in the 3D world, we move everything in the scene to the right. That is why the View Matrix is the inverse of the Camera Matrix.

For more info about Model, View and Projection matrices (and more) check out [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).